# Problemas con Jenkins y Pruebas Unitarias del Algoritmo KNN

Tags: python, jenkins, knn

Estoy teniendo dificultades con Jenkins, ya que es la primera vez que trabajo con él y no entiendo cómo aplicarlo. Mi objetivo es realizar pruebas unitarias para el código de un repositorio que contiene el algoritmo KNN.

En particular, me siento perdido en cuanto a qué pruebas hacerle al repositorio, cómo llevarlas a cabo y cómo integrarlas en Jenkins. Por esta razón, me gustaría pedir ayuda en los siguientes puntos:

1. **Pruebas en Jenkins:** He investigado y he visto que las pruebas unitarias se pueden realizar en la sección "Build Steps" de Jenkins, pero los comandos de Windows que he utilizado allí me han dado error. ¿Podrían proporcionarme información sobre cómo hacer estas pruebas en Jenkins?
2. **Ejemplo de Pruebas Unitarias:** Entiendo que las pruebas unitarias deben diseñarse por uno mismo, pero no tengo idea de qué pruebas podría hacerle al algoritmo KNN. Agradecería mucho si alguien pudiera facilitarme un ejemplo para ayudarme a entender.

Realmente me siento desesperado, ya que este es mi Trabajo de Fin de Grado y no estoy avanzando. Les agradecería mucho cualquier ayuda que pudieran darme.

Saludos cordiales.